# Is there a simple way to iterate through pairs in a Ruby hash in order of addition (i.e. oldest first)?

Tags: ruby, hash, ruby-1.8

I create an empty hash `chickens`, and key-value pairs are then added over time.

```
chickens = {} 
chickens.merge!("Davison"=>"plucky")
chickens.merge!("Mortimer"=>"sullen")
chickens.merge!("Chauncey"=>"forlorn") 

for name,mood in chickens do puts "#{name}: #{mood}" end
```

produces

```
Mortimer: sullen
Chauncey: forlorn
Davison: plucky
```

but I don't desire this. How do I cycle through the chickens in the order they were added?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: update your Ruby.  Ruby 1.9 is years old and works the way you want (as does current Ruby, 2.0).  If you insist on ancient, unsupported Ruby, there's an OrderedHash class available via a gem:

```
gem install orderedhash
```

Your code would then become:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'orderedhash'

chickens = OrderedHash.new
# The rest stays the same
```

Again, I recommend instead just upgrading your Ruby installation.

P.S. Your code would be *much* more Ruby-like if you iterate over the Hash like this:

```
chickens.each do |name, mood|
  puts "#{name}: #{mood}"
end
```

Comment: I didn't know my Ruby was old! I'm using CodeAcademy Labs, which I assumed would be current.  
Do you know of another site like that, that has the current Ruby?  
  
  
 Also, you don't have to be so mean. Obviously (from the question I asked) I'm very new to this, and obviously I want to be using the current, supported version!

Comment: I don't see any meanness here.  Just straight-up matter-of-fact.

Comment: Thing is, why would anyone, especially a total noob who would ask a question like I asked, "insist on using ancient, unsupported Ruby"? He knew I was using it by mistake, and didn't know any better. How couldn't he have?

Comment: @user2493615 I'm not too familiar with Rubies-in-the-browser, but http://tryruby.org is at least closer to modern -- it's 1.9.2 and supports ordered Hashes.

Comment: Oh, how about this one? Does this look appropriate? 
http://www.compileonline.com/execute_ruby_online.php

Comment: @user2493615 I'm very sorry if something in my tone sounded mean to you.  I assure you that no meanness was intended.  The fact of the matter is that 1.8.7 is considered unsupported and isn't good for using or learning with.

Comment: Well thank you for telling me that! I had no idea.  
Codeacademy should update their site!

Comment: @user2493615 It looks like that one is also on 1.8.7.

Comment: Doesn't it say up top, Ruby 2.0.0p0?

Comment: @user2493615 It does, but it's apparently incorrect.  `puts VERSION` shows 1.8.7, and a quick test shows 1.8-era unordered Hashes.

Comment: Ok, what is the simplest way to get Ruby on my system?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32199/discussion-between-darshan-computing-and-user2493615)

Comment: @user2493615 "why would anyone, especially a total noob who would ask a question like I asked, "insist on using ancient, unsupported Ruby"? He knew I was using it by mistake, and didn't know any better. How couldn't he have? " You misread and make assumptions about Darshan's comment. There was nothing wrong with what he said. Often we see people who can't/won't update, so he was addressing the "can't" update aspect I believe. He has repeatedly been very friendly and accurate in his answers so I think he was being consistent here. To summarize, he said "try OrderedHash".

Comment: @user2493615, regarding authoritative information about Ruby's state, look to http://www.ruby-lang.org. You shouldn't blindly trust other sites, even Stack Overflow because web pages get stale. Also, http://www.ruby-lang.org has links to the current Ruby installs. I'd recommend looking at [RVM](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) to install Ruby in a sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

@DarshanComputing began talking about making the code more Ruby-like, but here's how I would do the sample code in its entirety:

```
chickens = {} 
chickens["Davison"] = "plucky"
chickens["Mortimer"] = "sullen"
chickens["Chauncey"] = "forlorn"

chickens.each do |name, mood| 
  puts "#{name}: #{mood}"
end
```

Using `merge` is fine, but it's also verbose. You'll see a lot of Ruby programmers take the more simple path and add the key/value pair directly, rather than rely on a mutating method.

Using `for` to loop over something is definitely not Ruby-like. Though the language supports it, its use is eschewed by Ruby developers consistently. The reason is, `for name, mood ...` adds `name` and `mood` to the local variables, unlike `each` which confines them inside the `do` block. Littering the variable space with temporary variables is bad-form. For instance, after running the original code I can do:

```
[7] (pry) main: 0> name
"Chauncey"
[8] (pry) main: 0> mood
"forlorn"
```